# expect script not working with bash script

Tags: linux, shell, expect

I want a script that ssh to remote server and then run a script which is at my local machine and then store the output on my local machine

Expect script for ssh to remote server:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set Timeout 2
        set IPaddress 10.118.137.78
        set Username "username"
        set Password "password"


        spawn ssh $Username@$IPaddress
        expect "ssword:"
        send "$Password\r"
```

script to be run on remote machine and gather the data:

```
#!/bin/sh

for serveraddress in `cat list.out`
do
"seeisso $serveraddress | grep -E -i ' os |proddropdown'"
done >> getos
```

===
Not sure how to :
1. combine both and get the result.
2 in expect script it does not takes the \r and returns to newline.

Answer (score 1):

Quick sample

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
set Username "user"
set password "pass"
set ipaddress "host"
set script "script-name"

spawn $env(SHELL)
send -- "ssh $Username@$ipaddress $script\r"
expect "assword: "
send -- "$password\r"
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

That will work to execute the script on the remote side.  I didn't toy with it too much but when it's done you have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit expect.  At this point I'd be setting up ssh keys for a small environment and for a larger use puppet or something to manage it then for even larger go for single sign-on probably kerberos.

Comment: I have to put script on remote machine?

Comment: is there a away i can execute the script which is on my local machine ?

Comment: what are the -- dashes after "send" for?